# How to reinstall Eclipse on Linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, reinstall

I used the Software Manager in Linux Mint to install Eclipse Platform. It was working yesterday, however, now whenever I run it I get the following error message:

> The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.

I tried uninstalling it and then installing it again. Much to my confusion, this did not work. The error message still persists. It implies Eclipse requires a shared dependency that it cannot find. Is there anyway to find out what this is and install it? I've tried 'apt-get dist-upgrade' to update packages but this didn't resolve the issue at hand.

Comment: This sounds like more of a problem with `apt` than Eclipse…? Perhaps you'd have better luck over at ServerFault?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using linux and Eclipse for years, but I would never suggest anyone install Eclipse from the platform repositories for any distribution.

Get your eclipse zips directly from Eclipse.org

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just "Google it."  (Or, in my case, "DuckDuckGo it.")  Put the exact error-message text in double quotes to tell the search-engine that you are looking for the exact phrase.

DDG promptly referred me to this page:  http://veeddie.blogspot.com/2010/06/eclipse-executable-launcher-was-unable.html